# Why can't a UISplitViewController be the rootViewController property of a UIWindow?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

When creating the initial view in iPhone applications you can set the IBOutlet rootViewController property of the main UIWindow to your default view controller, but this doesn't work with a UISplitViewController.

If I do this I don't receive any compile errors, and the app runs, but no screen is displayed on app startup.

The way recommended by the Apple docs for UISplitViewController is to do the following within your app delegate launch method:

```
[window addSubview:splitViewController.view];
```

I was just wondering why UISplitViewController needed this different approach.

Comment: OK, I feel a little stupid now. It IS possible, as long as you're not a complete muppet. Thanks everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course that works. In fact, it's what the Split View-based Application template from Xcode 4.0.2 does (SDK 4.3).

Split view controllers are only intended for iPad, not iPhone, though. Are you trying this on an iPhone project?

**Update**

Since iOS 8 it is available on all devices.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it isn't possible? `rootViewController` needs to be an `UIViewController` and `UISplitViewController` *is* an `UIViewController`. Try restarting Xcode. If that's not working, there's a big chance it's a bug, so I'ld suggest you file it at Apple's bug reporter.

Comment: I created a new project using the split view template in xcode 4 and low and behold it IS possible to set the rootViewController property of a UIWindow to a UISplitViewController. The mistake I was making was not instantiating the detailed child view controller properly (the one on the right). Thanks for the speedy response.

Answer (score 1):

I dont have any problems making a UISplitViewController UIWindow rootViewController.  In fact, the Split View app template generates code that configures the app this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
DLog(@"Method: homeScreenViewController");
        
    UISplitViewController *svc = (UISplitViewController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewiPad"];

    //[self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
    
    UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0];
    window.rootViewController = svc;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    
    /*
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
    {
        if ([window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
        {
            window.rootViewController = svc;
            //UIViewController *con =  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeiPad"];
            //[window addSubview:con.view];
            [window makeKeyAndVisible];
        }
    }
     */
```

//vKj